# Codeigniter - Like Query Not Working with Search String

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

In my PHP - Codeigniter function(), I gave the following command:

```
function get_cust($search='David')
{
$query = 'select pp.first_name from Cust pp where'; 
$query .= ' pp.first_name LIKE "%'.escape_like_str($search).'%")';
print_r(mysql_real_escape_string($query));
}
```

But while i executed the output in browser:

```
select pp.first_name from Cust pp where pp.first_name LIKE 'Úvid%'
```

Is it anyway so i can get it like:

```
select pp.first_name from Cust pp where pp.first_name LIKE '%David%'
```

I have tried using `addslashes()`, `mysql_real_escape_string()` as well. Do anyone have idea on how to change `'Úvid%'` to become as `'%David%'`
I am using PHP 5.4 on my localmachine so i couldn't use `mysqli`.

Comment: What is inside `$search`?

Comment: What's the code for `escape_like_str`?

Comment: @RonnieOosting, "David" is inside search!.

Comment: Can you please try this? 
sprintf("select pp.first_name from Cust pp where pp.first_name LIKE '%%s%'",
,mysql_real_escape_string($search))

Comment: 'pp.first_name LIKE ' . "%" . escape_like_str($search) . "%" . ' '

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine with your code. `%Da` is a [html entity](https://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html).

> Ú Ú       %DA     Ú     Capital U, acute accent

So, it is just a problem with outputting data, internally your query text is **correct**. Try another string as search request, not starting with `Da`, or just execute mysql query and see it's results.

Comment: Yeah it worked for all other strings! except "Da" and "De"

Comment: Well. That's my question. I want to know how to get it worked for "Da" and "De" too.

Comment: It will work! `%Da` is converted to `U` only when you __output query text as html__. Internally your query text is passed to `mysql` which will use it as simple text __without__ converting `%Da` to `U`.

Comment: Ok. How can i get rid off that "Output query text as html"? or get a way to show a proper html format?

Comment: Don't output query text?

Comment: Well. query text working correctly, But my search is not functioning. See I want to search "David" from the list of records. But its not working! Its taking it as "Úvid".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use **query builder** in Codeigniter. You can find the [documentation of like here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-similar-data). It will look like this:

```
$name = 'David';

$this->db
  ->select('pp.first_name')
  ->like('pp.first_name', $name, 'both')
   >get('Cust');
```

Comment: Yeah @gazdagergo, I tried with 'both' and 'before' as well. But only 'after' worked!.